Ampscript UpdateSingleSalesforceObject Function in Loop
Im getting a 500 - error on my code and can't figure out whats causing it. Im trying to build a custom preference center (cloud page) that updates corresponding contact point consent records in salesforce. The first record is updating, but then the error throws. Ive looked at the payload and am trying to log to a DE with errors but it looks like the loop is terminating before the second iteration. Full code below:
       %%[ /* Retrieve subscriberKey and consent information */
        SET @subscriberKey = RequestParameter("subscriberKey")

        IF NOT EMPTY(@subscriberKey) THEN
            OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Subscriber Key: ", @subscriberKey, "</p>"))

            /* Retrieve the Contact details */
            SET @row = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact", "Email, FirstName, IndividualId", "Id", "=", @subscriberKey)
            IF ROWCOUNT(@row) > 0 THEN
                SET @firstName = FIELD(ROW(@row, 1), "FirstName")
                SET @IndividualId = FIELD(ROW(@row, 1), "IndividualId")
                OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Individual ID: ", @IndividualId, "</p>"))
            ELSE
                OUTPUT("<p>No Contact records found.</p>")
            ENDIF

            /* Retrieve Contact Point Email records */
            SET @row2 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("ContactPointEmail", "ID", "ParentId", "=", @IndividualId, "IsPrimary", "=", "true")
            IF ROWCOUNT(@row2) > 0 THEN
                SET @contactPointEmailId = FIELD(ROW(@row2, 1), "ID")
                OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Contact Point Email ID: ", @contactPointEmailId, "</p>"))

                /* Retrieve Consent Records */
                SET @row3 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("ContactPointConsent", "ID, PrivacyConsentStatus, DataUsePurposeID", "ContactPointId", "=", @contactPointEmailId)
                OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Number of Consent Records Retrieved: ", ROWCOUNT(@row3), "</p>"))
            ELSE
                OUTPUT("<p>No Contact Point Email records found.</p>")
            ENDIF
        ELSE
            OUTPUT("<p>Subscriber Key is empty.</p>")
        ENDIF
    ]%%

    <!-- Dynamic Greeting -->
    <h2> %%=v(@firstName)=%%, view and update your preferences below: </h2>

    <!-- Start the form -->
    <form id="myform" action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="subscriberKey" value="%%=v(@subscriberKey)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="contactPointEmailId" value="%%=v(@contactPointEmailId)=%%" />

        <!-- Consent Management Records -->
        %%[ 
            IF ROWCOUNT(@row3) > 0 THEN
                FOR @i = 1 TO ROWCOUNT(@row3) DO
                    SET @privacyConsentStatus = FIELD(ROW(@row3, @i), "PrivacyConsentStatus")
                    SET @dataUsePurposeID = FIELD(ROW(@row3, @i), "DataUsePurposeID")
                    SET @consentID = FIELD(ROW(@row3, @i), "ID")
                    
                    /* Retrieve Data Use Purpose details */
                    SET @row4 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("DataUsePurpose", "Name, Description", "Id", "=", @dataUsePurposeID)
                    IF ROWCOUNT(@row4) > 0 THEN
                        SET @consentName = FIELD(ROW(@row4, 1), "Name")
                        SET @description = FIELD(ROW(@row4, 1), "Description")
                        OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Iteration ", @i, " - Consent ID: ", @consentID, " - PrivacyConsentStatus: ", @privacyConsentStatus, "</p>"))
        ]%%

        <div class="form-group checkbox-label">
            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="status_%%=v(@i)=%%" value="OptIn" %%[IF @privacyConsentStatus == "OptIn" THEN]%% checked %%[ENDIF]%% />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="checkbox-content">
                <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">%%=v(@consentName)=%%</span>
                <p style="font-size: 14px; color: #555;">%%=v(@description)=%%</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        %%[ 
                    ENDIF
                NEXT @i 
            ELSE
                OUTPUT("<p>No consent records found.</p>")
            ENDIF 
        ]%%

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="submit" value="Update Preferences" />
        </div>
    </form>

    %%[ 
        IF RequestParameter("submitted") == "true" THEN
            SET @rowCount = ROWCOUNT(@row3)
            SET @logDE = "ConsentUpdateLogs"

            FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO
                SET @consentID = FIELD(ROW(@row3, @i), "ID")
                SET @iterationNumber = @i
                SET @errorMessage = "No error"
                SET @updateStatus = "Not executed"

                /* Additional logging for debugging */
                SET @privacyConsentStatus = FIELD(ROW(@row3, @i), "PrivacyConsentStatus")
                SET @dataUsePurposeID = FIELD(ROW(@row3, @i), "DataUsePurposeID")
                OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Iteration ", @iterationNumber, " - Retrieved PrivacyConsentStatus: ", @privacyConsentStatus, ", DataUsePurposeID: ", @dataUsePurposeID, "</p>"))

                IF NOT EMPTY(@consentID) THEN
                    SET @checkboxValue = RequestParameter(CONCAT("status_", @i))

                    /* Log before update */
                    SET @logStatusBefore = UpsertDE(@logDE, 1, 
                        "IterationNumber", @iterationNumber,
                        "ConsentID", @consentID,
                        "CheckboxValue", @checkboxValue,
                        "UpdateStatus", "Before Update"
                    )

                    IF NOT EMPTY(@checkboxValue) THEN
                        TRY
                            IF @checkboxValue == "OptIn" THEN
                                SET @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("ContactPointConsent", @consentID, "PrivacyConsentStatus", "OptIn")
                            ELSE
                                SET @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("ContactPointConsent", @consentID, "PrivacyConsentStatus", "OptOut")
                            ENDIF

                            IF EMPTY(@updateStatus) OR @updateStatus == "false" THEN
                                SET @errorMessage = "Update failed or returned an empty response."
                                SET @updateStatus = "false"
                            ELSE
                                SET @updateStatus = "Success"
                            ENDIF

                        CATCH @caughtError
                            SET @updateStatus = "false"
                            SET @errorMessage = CONCAT("Caught Error during update of Consent ID: ", @consentID, ". Error: ", @caughtError)
                        ENDTRY

                    ELSE
                        SET @updateStatus = "false"
                        SET @errorMessage = CONCAT("Checkbox value is empty for iteration: ", @iterationNumber)
                    ENDIF

                    /* Log the result of the update */
                    SET @logStatusAfter = UpsertDE(@logDE, 1, 
                        "IterationNumber", @iterationNumber,
                        "ConsentID", @consentID,
                        "UpdateStatus", @updateStatus,
                        "CheckboxValue", @checkboxValue,
                        "ErrorMessage", @errorMessage
                    )

                    /* Output to page for debugging */
                    OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Iteration ", @iterationNumber, " - Consent ID: ", @consentID, " - Status: ", @updateStatus, " - Error: ", @errorMessage, "</p>"))

                ELSE
                    /* Log if ConsentID is empty */
                    SET @errorMessage = CONCAT("Consent ID is empty for iteration: ", @i)
                    SET @logStatusEmpty = UpsertDE(@logDE, 1, 
                        "IterationNumber", @i,
                        "ConsentID", "N/A",
                        "UpdateStatus", "false",
                        "CheckboxValue", "N/A",
                        "ErrorMessage", @errorMessage
                    )
                    OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>", @errorMessage, "</p>"))
                ENDIF

                /* Log each iteration completion */
                OUTPUT(CONCAT("<p>Completed iteration ", @i, "</p>"))
            NEXT @i
        ENDIF
    ]%%

